# HDD crash, 2s periodic sound occurs in use

Tags: hard-drive, crash, sata

[YouTube sound demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRAFWxlraVk?t=7s)

Seagate 2TB drive, bought in 2013. Used as network storage.

There were problems with reading some volumes. There are about 2000 broken sectors. I plugged it into a computer and copied contents.

While formatting it crashed. I turned off computer and unplugged drive.

I didn't drop it. The drive produces strange sounds and vibrates

I'm not hardware expert, but I think, that Read/Write head produces this sound, and platter(s) have been broken.

[image: problem]

### Is it fixable? What might be the problem?

Comment: "Is it fixable?" - Yes; It might be possible but only by a company which specializes in data recovery.  If you open the drive yourself you will guarantee any chance you have will become absolutely no chance of data recovery

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for comment. My dilemma is buy new one or repair this. I'm going to use it as archive. Money is criteria.

Comment: As far as a physical crack in a platter, that is unlikely... the heads skate over the surface on a microns-thick air gap -- even the smallest crack would completely destroy the heads. If you've been able to recover any data, that's the best that you could do. BTW, you can take the drive apart for the rare-earth magnets, if you're discarding the drive.

Comment: Replace it. As an archive it is useless.

Comment: No, it cannot be repaired. That service is for data recovery alone and costs hundreds of dollars. You can buy a 2TB hard drive for under $100. I would recommend avoiding Seagate like the plague.  I've replaced hundreds of bad hard drives. 80% of them are seagate. They stopped making reliable hard drives about 10 years ago.